# p-value over q-value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I am trying to figure out when (during multiple testing) to use $p$-values and when to use $q$-values.

[This student thesis](http://pages.pomona.edu/~jsh04747/Student%20Theses/Kimes_Final.pdf) explains how this particular theorem (Eq. 11 in the paper) allows one to interpret the $q$-value as a simple conditional probability. According to the student, "the $q$-value is the $p$-value with the conditional statement and event of interest reversed.

The student later gives an example:

> "If a giant meteor were heading toward the earth a hypothesis interesting to test might be that the world was ending soon. A $p$-value calculation would produce the probability of an event as catastrophic or more than a meteor heading towards the earth happening give that the world was ending. The $q$-value would be the probability of the world ending given the observation of an event as catastrophic as a meteor heading towards Earth. In this case, the $q$-value, rather than the $p$-value answers a much more natural question. It makes substantially more intuitive sense to be interested in how likely it is that the world will end than how likely the event of the meteor was given the world is indeed ending."

This scenario makes sense as to why one would use the $q$-value over a $p$-value. But in what scenarios would it make sense to use a $p$-value over a $q$-value?

Comment: "... as catastrophic or more..." seems to misunderstand hypothesis testing altogether.  It appears to confuse *magnitude of effect* with the (inverse) of *probability under the null hypothesis.*  As such I cannot make any sense of the quotation.

Comment: @whuber I see what you're saying about magnitude of effect, so what if we interpreted "...as catastrophic or more..." as "...as large as or larger than this giant meteor..." (assuming probability decreases as meteor size increases)? Also, I believe the null hypothesis should be "the world is not ending" rather than "the world is ending".

Comment: I believe that first remark reflects the same confusion. Hypothesis testing concerns *probabilities* rather than sizes of meteors, costs of damage, or anything else.  When people write "as extreme or more extreme than" in the context of hypothesis testing, then they mean--or *ought* to mean--extreme in terms of *probabilities of critical regions.* The theory that justifies this is the [Neyman-Pearson Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) which, as you can see, is expressed solely in terms of probabilities (via likelihood functions).